# Search content withing the documents in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

Do we have any out of box search wherein we can search the content within the document(.doc, .xls, .pdf) and display the result?

Comment: What's your SharePoint version and edition?

Comment: Sharepoint Server 2010 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 all office document types are indexed and the content (both text and properties) are search-able. For PDF you have to install a 3rd party iFilter to index the content of PDF documents.

In 2013 the content of all those file types is indexed out of the box. (A different process is used for content indexing in 2013.)